# Accepting SOAP envelope

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, soap

Cheers,

I have a soap webservice written in c#, that takes in an XMLDocument as parameter...

```
    [WebMethod]
    [SoapDocumentMethod(ResponseNamespace = "http://ns.ctb.nl/flex/2012-1")]
    public string stuurReflexBericht(XmlDocument m) //XElement m
    {
    //do something
}
```

and Im using Boomerang, an extension for Google Chrome to test the service.

Boomerang creates this Request Body:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://ctb.nl/webservices">
    <x:Header/>
    <x:Body>
        <web:stuurReflexBericht>
            <web:m>
                My XML Body
            </web:m>
        </web:stuurReflexBericht>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

and this works, the service receives the xml message. However, the consumer of the service wants to send the message as:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://ctb.nl/webservices">
    <x:Header/>
    <x:Body>
                My XML Body
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

and when they do that, the XMLDocument is null.

The consumer does not want to change their code, so its up to me to make the adjustments.

I tried changing the parameter datatype from XMLDocument to string in the hopes that it would work, but it does not.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

TIA

Comment: You want to make changes in your webservices based on new xml request. Right?

Comment: yes thats right. so that the new request would work.

Comment: still no takers?

Comment: @RandyAdanza why not use `XElement` and leverage LINQtoXML? It should be a trivial transformation if all you need is to map between the two formats you've shown